# matrix to array with every other row reversed

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I have to convert matrix to array. For example

```
[
   [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   [ 4, 5, 6 ],
   [ 7, 8, 9 ],
]
```

should convert to [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9 ].
I write a code

```
function sortMatrix (matrix) {
    let newArr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        newArr = newArr.concat(matrix[i]);
    }
    return newArr
}
```

but output is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]. How can I do so that on the second line, it counts from the end

Comment: Welcome!
What are you trying to achieve = what do you call it?
Matrix (2D Array) to Array (1D) **IS** `matrix = array.flat()`.  
With your data: 
`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].flat()` **IS** `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Comment: @iAmOren but the expected result is *not* that, it's `[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]` - the middle array is reversed.

Comment: @VLAZ, I got that, thanks, but that's not matrix to array.
Title should read: "matrix to array with every other row reversed" - if that's what the op wants - we have no clue about 4 or more rows/columns/has to be square/etc.  Unless this is some kind of math that I haven't learned yet...

Comment: Tom, fix your title and body of question without changing math...
Give details on what you want, what to do in case of more than 4 rows/columns/has to be square, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code - reverse sub-arrays at odd indexes.

Note: since `Array.reverse()` mutates the original array, we need to shallow clone it using array spread.

```js
function sortMatrix(matrix) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    const arr = matrix[i];
    newArr = newArr.concat(i % 2 ? [...arr].reverse() : arr);
  }
  return newArr;
}

const matrix = [
 [ 1, 2, 3 ],
 [ 4, 5, 6 ],
 [ 7, 8, 9 ],
];

const result = sortMatrix(matrix);

console.log(result);
```

Another option is to use `Array.flatMap()`, and reverse sub-arrays at odd indexes.

```js
function sortMatrix(matrix) {
  return matrix.flatMap((arr, i) => i % 2 ? [...arr].reverse() : arr);
}

const matrix = [
   [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   [ 4, 5, 6 ],
   [ 7, 8, 9 ],
];

const result = sortMatrix(matrix);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to create it.

```js
const arr = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
]

const flatArray = (arr) => arr.reverse().reduce((acc, curr)=> {
  acc.push(...curr.reverse());
  return acc;
},[])

console.log(flatArray(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `flat` function

```js
array = [
   [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   [ 4, 5, 6 ],
   [ 7, 8, 9 ],
]

console.log(array.flat());
```

Comment: You'd be correct if you wanted to flatten a matrix to an array.
Unfortunately, the op is confusing us: op **doesn't** want to flatten a matrix to an array.
We can only guess what the op wants.